# Rally SDK: Retrieving all available State values for Defects

Tags: javascript, rally

I want to retrieve all available State values for Rally Defect.
The following code works good for Features:

```
this.states = [];
    this.stateStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['_ref', 'name']
    });

    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'State',
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [
            {
                property: 'Enabled',
                operation: '=',
                value: true
            },
            {
                property: 'TypeDef.Name',
                operation: '=',
                value: 'Feature'
            }
        ],
        listeners: {
            load: function (store, data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    this.stateStore.add({ '_ref': data[i].data._ref, 'name': data[i].data.Name });
                }
                this.statesLoaded = true;
                this._initialLoad();
            },
            scope: this
        }
    });
```

With this approach, we load all available State values for features. However, when I change 'Feature' TypeDef.Name filter to 'Defect', I get nothing despite the fact that there are many active States for Defect defined.
Does anybody know why this happens and how get State values for Defect?
Maybe Defects use some other states, not like features, suer stories etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WS API there is a full State object that represents State of PortfolioItems. It is different from the State or ScheduleState of such artifacts as Defect or UserStory, which are only string values in the dropdown field. There is no such thing as State.Name for a Defect.

Using promises, this may look like this:

```
launch: function(){
    this._getModel().then({
        success: this._getAllowedValues,
        scope:this
    }).then({//...})
},

 _getModel:function(){
        return Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type:'Defect'
        });
    },

 _getAllowedValues:function(model){
        var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
        var allowedStateValues = [];
        model.getField('State').getAllowedValueStore().load({
            callback: function(records,operation,success){
                Ext.Array.each(records,function(allowedValue){
                    allowedStateValues.push(allowedValue.get('StringValue'));
                });
                if(success){
                    deferred.resolve(allowedStateValues);
                }
                else{
                    deferred.reject();
                }

            }
        }) ;
        return deferred.promise; 
    },//...
```

See [this example](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/active-defects-chart/blob/master/App.js) that retrieves allowed values for Priority and Severity of defects. Since those allow null values, null values are removed in this app example, but State does not have null values so you may skip that step.

Comment: Thanks! It works. What's a bit interesting however is that ObjectID for each State in the allowed values is 0, but when I retrieve the Defect history (a regular SnapshotStore with _TypeHierarchy: defect), each Defect snapshot contains State code. Do you know where this code can be found?

Comment: @MyUserName you're welcome. Which code you are trying to locate? If it the one I posted, it's not a full app, I just wrote that code fragment to provide an example with my answer. As far as ObjectID, LookbackAPI from which SnapshotStore retrieves data is different. Lookback get's Revisions directly from the db and stores it in mongodb - it is not using WS API as the rest of AppSDK. With Lookback, for most things you get an OID and you have to hydrate them, but that's not the case with WS API

Comment: No, it's not about your example which really helped me. It's about my code that loads Defects snapshot. So, the IDs of the states are some values in MongoDB, and I just need to hydrate the State and work with string values instead. Thank you again:).

Comment: @MyUserName, see also: "Hydrating Dropdown Values" https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual/hydratingdropdownfields